# Redirect category archives to pages

Tags: categories

I'd prefer to not use the category pages of my WordPress install - my question is - does anyone see a "WordPress" contradiction or an error that might arise if I redirect "Category" pages to another page? Would I be doing something against the "integrity" of the WordPress architecture and/ or construction?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're not going to use the category pages, why use categories at all?

Comment: One may not want to show categories in the front-end, but systematically manage the content in the backend. By the way, this is kind one the use cases for a headless WordPress

Comment: @henry You can do the redirect, it's up to you... But you probably just need to customize the category pages, or change their permalink structures.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: no contradiction, no error, no "sin" against the integrity.

WordPress is flexible enough that you may decide to use what is best for use case. Wanna get rid of a taxonomy or all taxonomies? Go for it. In fact, i think this is kinda one the use cases for a headless WordPress.

Comment: FYI @jacobpeattie I am using categories to fire certain widgets based on the categories used within my functions.php

Ok cool. 

So I think I will. 

It’s really just my design and an seo thing. 

Thanks for all support